# How can a Flutter plugin for web make assets available to the main index.html?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a Dart class that uses package:js to access javascript loaded by web/index.html with a `<script>` tag. I'm trying to refactor the Flutter widget that uses it into a plugin. How can I make the javascript file currently in web/ accessible to index.html from the plugin?

Comment: I am not sure so I prefer posting a comment. I searched for this myself and arrived at the conclusion that this is not possible. This would explain why some plugins like firebase necessitate that you manually add a line to `index.html` (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web). Just a theory though ^^

Comment: @Lulupointu Thanks for the comment. That's what I've concluded as well but hope I missed something since other Flutter platforms have a way to incorporate "native" assets. FWIW I think my worst-case-scenario right now is a script that creates symlinks or copies the files using https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#executables to make it available. It requires the developer to manually run the script after pub get or upgrade, which isn't ideal.